# C# loop positive and negative numbers

Tags: c#, loops, numbers

I need help with a simple C# program. Simpley yet I don't know the solution. The problem is here: I need to loop (or print on the screen) all numbers in this order: 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, etc. until they reach 100.
Do you have any ideas how to do that? For now I've done something like that:

```
for (int i = -2; i <= 100; i += 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

But I can't get it to work like the order I want, I know I'm doing something wrong in the i += 1 section but I can't figure out how to do that! Thank you for your support.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Think a bit. It's **really** very simple.

Comment: Solution without code: Instead of counting from -2 to 100, count from 2 to 100 and alter the sign you print to the console on each iteration.

Comment: I wouldn't say there is anything wrong about `i += 1` (even though it *could* be equivalently written as `i++`). However, please consider that you do not need to print *exactly* the value of `i`; you can use `i`  for counting and print something computed based on `i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can multiple with `-1` on odd numbers, therefore use the [`%` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
{
    int val = i % 2 == 1 ? i * -1 : i;
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/pCXLpt)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you really much! It worked, and it is yet so simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple if we use `modulo`

The steps are faily straight forward. If we will notice the it's the same solution as printing 2-100 but with 1 little twist, for the odd places the number `i` should be at his negative sign. So the solution will be the same.

**Steps:**

1. Loop i to 100
2. For every iteration we will decide if it's odd or even.
3. If `i` is even will multiply it by 1 that will result with `i` of course.
    else, that means it's odd and thus, resulting in
   multiplying with -1, resulting with `minus i`.

**Code**

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * (i%2 == 0 ? 1 : -1));
}
```

Comment: @AndyG, I don't think anything can be overkill for this question :)

Comment: I'd say the conditional is clearer.  All the info required to understand it is right there in the loop, so you don't have to trace through the loop or make inferences about the sign.

Comment: For reference, one could also say `Console.WriteLine(i%2==0 ? i : -i);`.

Comment: @cHao, Indeed, i wanted to improve it, but than i saw BLUEPIXY used that in his solution, so i chose not to edit mine, otherwise it won't be fair and also it's good for the author to see many solutions. But yeah i liked that more :)

Comment: @AndyG, Sorry it's appears I was wrong, there is an **overkill** was for this solution. I just saw Sergey Berezovskiy solution. The author having difficulties with this loop and his giving him `LINQ`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=2;i<=100;++i){
    Console.WriteLine(i % 2 == 1 ? -i : i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate from 2 to 100 one by one (yes, all are positive values)
Then in loop body you should invert sign on each iteration (by multiplying on "-1") and print the result on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Using bitwise and to spot the odd numbers:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i += 1)
{
  int toPrint = i

  if((i & 1)==1)
  {
    // It's odd
    toPrint = -toPrint;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(toPrint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we all did this task in school:

```
Enumerable.Range(2, Int32.MaxValue - 1)
          .TakeWhile(i => i <= 100)
          .Select(i => i % 2 == 0 ? i : -i)
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Why the `.TakeWhile`, rather than just saying `Enumerable.Range(2, 100 - 1)`?

Comment: @cHao it was `Enumerable.Range(2, 100 - 1)` in previous edit, but then I decided to make it less acceptable for homework

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                int j = -i;
                Console.WriteLine(j);
            }
            else
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```